# Want result with out using subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT  
   ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by tblProductTemplateHdr.product_ID 
                    order by tblProductTemplateHdr.product_ID, tblProcessSequence.sl_No) AS rno,
   tblProductTemplateHdr.product_ID
   ,tblProductProcessHdr.process_ID
   ,tblProcessSequence.sl_No    
FROM 
   Production.tblProcessSequence 
INNER JOIN 
   Production.tblProductProcessHdr ON tblProductProcessHdr.product_Process_ID = tblProcessSequence.product_Process_ID AND tblProductProcessHdr.isQC_Need = 1  
INNER JOIN 
   Production.tblProductTemplateHdr ON tblProductTemplateHdr.product_Temp_ID = tblProductProcessHdr.product_Temp_ID
```

I want the row with maximum `sl_No` in each `product_Id` without using a subquery, this the result obtained by running this query want to apply filtering on same query

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to a) rewrite your query just a little, and b) I'd recommend using **table aliases** to make your query more readable.

Try this:

```
;WITH ProductData AS
(
  SELECT  
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pth.Product_ID 
                        ORDER BY pth.Product_ID, ps.sl_No DESC) AS rno,
     tph.product_ID,
     tph.process_ID,
     ps.sl_No    
  FROM 
     Production.tblProcessSequence ps
  INNER JOIN 
     Production.tblProductProcessHdr pph ON tph.product_Process_ID = ps.product_Process_ID 
                                         AND pph.isQC_Need = 1  
  INNER JOIN 
     Production.tblProductTemplateHdr tph ON tph.product_Temp_ID = pph.product_Temp_ID 
)
SELECT *
FROM 
    ProductData
WHERE
    rno = 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function partitions your data by `Product_ID` and within each partition, it orders the rows by `sl_No DESC` - so the highest value of `sl_No` gets the `rno = 1` value (all others get higher numbers, in each partition)

Comment: You cannot reference column aliases in the `WHERE` clause. This query will fail: _Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Invalid column name 'rno'._ It is also an error carried forward if you like because the OP did the same, but ordering by the same column you are partitioning by in the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` Function is pointless.

Comment: @GarethD: spot on - fixed my answer by using a CTE (Common Table Expression) to "encapsulate" the query and thus be able to use the `rno` column in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 1):

You can use another windowed function:

```
MAX(tblProcessSequence.sl_No) OVER(PARTITION BY tblProductTemplateHdr.product_ID)
```

**ADDENDUM**

Just to give the full query in context in case the above was not clear:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tempHdr.Product_ID  ORDER BY Seq.sl_No DESC) AS rno,
        tempHdr.product_ID,
        procHdr.process_ID,
        Seq.sl_No,
        MAX(Seq.sl_No) OVER(PARTITION BY tblProductTemplateHdr.Product_ID) AS Max_SL_No
FROM    Production.tblProcessSequence Seq
        INNER JOIN Production.tblProductProcessHdr procHdr
            ON Seq.product_Process_ID = tblProductProcessHdr.product_Process_ID 
            AND procHdr.isQC_Need = 1  
        INNER JOIN Production.tblProductTemplateHdr tempHdr
            ON tempHdr.product_Temp_ID = procHdr.product_Temp_ID
```